# How can I have several inherited classes together in the same array?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a few classes, `ObjDef`, `PeopDef`, `NpcDef`, and `PlyDef`, such that `PlyDef` and `NpcDef` each seperately inherit `PeopDef`, and `PeopDef` inherits ObjDef. Each class has functionality that builds on the class before it, so it's important that `PeopDef::Tick` is called before `ObjDef::Tick`. I have every object stored in a `vector<ObjDef> object`, but when the main tick loop goes through them, I want them to call the original classes' Tick, rather than `ObjDef::Tick`, which is what the `vector<ObjDef>` currently makes it do. Is there any way to do this, or do I have to have a separate vector for each class?

Comment: It should work correctly if `Tick` is virtual.

Comment: Not true, it will only work if its virtual *and* the vector stores pointers or references instead of concrete objects.

Comment: You should start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store an ObjDef pointer (ObjDef* or a smart pointer) in the vector and make the Tick method virtual.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class ObjDef
{
public:
    virtual void Tick()
    {
        std::cout << "ObjDef::Tick\n";
    }
};

class PeopDef : public ObjDef
{
public:
    virtual void Tick()
    {
        std::cout << "PeopDef::Tick\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ObjDef>> objects;

    std::shared_ptr<ObjDef> obj(new ObjDef());
    std::shared_ptr<ObjDef> peop(new PeopDef());

    objects.push_back(obj);
    objects.push_back(peop);

    for (auto object : objects)
    {
        object->Tick();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depending upon object lifetime and memory management, it might be better to use `std::shared_ptr<ObjDef>` isntead.

Comment: Making the shared functions like `::Init` and `::Tick` virtual changed nothing, it still used the `ObjDef` functions. Changing `vector<ObjDef>` to `vector<ObjDef*>` makes around 40 "expression must have class type" errors.

Comment: I'd have to see more code to know what those errors are about, but I've added a quick example.

Comment: Although it isn't required here (because of `shared_ptr`), it's generally a good idea to define a `virtual` dtor if a class is intended to be stored via a base class pointer. (Actually, it's generally a good idea if the class is intended to be inherited from.)

Comment: I would recommend `std::unique_ptr` over `std::shared_ptr`.  The latter adds unnecessary overhead.